# If I change the name of a Core Data entity without setting renaming identifier, is the underlying data lost?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I made the mistake of not setting a renaming identifier when I changed an Entity name.  As users upgraded they seem to have lost their data.

I'm wondering if there's a way to manually migrate the data after this has happened?  Is the underlying persistent data store table still there with the data or is it deleted when there's no Entity anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is deleted and the data is lost.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  Too bad for me.  Luckily I have a dropbox backup system set up but it's going to be a pain explaining to users how to revert that file back.